# What is meaning of grey key in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

What is the meaning of the Grey key in PHPMYADMIN?

It's showing some index and not able to insert data

[Have added image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3dfx.png)

Comment: To see the table definition as text run the query show create table <tablename>

Comment: 'not able to insert data' - then you are violating a unique  key - but you don't say what you are trying to do, what do do if a duplicate is encountered and have not provided sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

If the column name is underlined then that indicates primary key otherwise it means you can't assign primary key to those columns.